# Why does my url return data sometimes and return error 404 not found others?

Tags: python, django

I have a django website, I have multiple INSTALLED_APPS listed in the settings.py.  One being the app that I am having trouble with.  This app loads properly sometimes, but randomly it returns with a 404 error.  I also have an ajax call from the app which also will go to the server and get the json data sometimes but even a second later when i try again it returns a 404 error.  If i run it again it will usually return the json data, but sometimes again the 404 error.  There is no difference in the call to the server that returns the data or the 404 error.  I can see in the debug of the 404 error response that it says 
"Using the URLconf defined in `website.urls`,
      Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:"
and the app path is not listed in the patterns but the other installed apps are.  Of course the times it works the path must be listed.  It seems to fail approximately 25% of the calls.  Is there something that is cached in django that reverts the URLconf to an earlier version that doesn't include the new installed app randomly?  Any suggestions are welcome, the randomness of the 404 happening or not is the most confusing...

Comment: This is in a production environment or on your development machine where you run `runserver`? Are you sure the hostname and port are the same each time?

Comment: It is a production environment and run through apache.  The hostname and port are the same with each call.  I can actually just see the network calls in chrome devtools and when it gives a 404 error I can right click and hit Replay XHR and it reacts the same, most of the time it returns the data properly but sometimes it returns 404 not found...

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple Django processes running, one of which hasn’t restarted after the last time you updated your code. Make sure all you mod_wsgi processes are restarted. Or you have multiple instances behind a load balancer, one of which isn’t updated.

Comment: We need to know more about your production setup.

Comment: Where do you see the debug info of the 404 actually?? In a log file on the machine? Maybe that can tell you if a specific process is handling the 404s compared to the ones not returning 404

Comment: I have done:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Shouldn't that restart all of the mod_wsgi processes or is there a different way to do it?  
I also tried:
sudo touch /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: The 404 errors are in the chrome devTools console.  The log file doesn't get written to when i get the 404, but does when the request actually works properly.

Comment: I ended up rebooting the entire machine and it seems to not have the issue anymore.  If you have any information about how to get the mod_wsgi processes restarted without rebooting i would greatly appreciate it.  I would think sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart should have done it, but i can clearly see that it needed something more.

Comment: That you see the 404 detailled error trace in you chrome devtools is a bad thing. In production your responses should never contain any trace backs. Is DEBUG=False???

Comment: Sorry I don’t have much experience with mod_wsgi. I use nginx and Gunicorn or uwsgi. Maybe if you have the issue again when updating you can open a new question here specifically on why apache2 restart doesn’t reboot all the wsgi processes?

Comment: I actually turned DEBUG on so I could figure out what was happening.  Thank you for your help.